# import xml to text Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

Ders..

I have below code to import XML from RSS web page to show text from xml to my Application ,, in manifests added permission internet and network state ..

```
import...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Thread() {
            final TextView urlTextOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
            final StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    String str;
                    URL url = new URL("My url");
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        text.append(str);
                    }
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored)
                {
                }
                urlTextOut.setText(text);
            }
        }.start();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But i have below error when I run it on my android emulator or phone direct :

```
>    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

....
 can you help me about this issue

Comment: You are suppose to update the view or layout from other thread.

Comment: Kindly share you code If possible

Comment: you mean layout code ?

Comment: Java or activity code. Or code snippet where you did tried to update the view or layout.

Comment: dear @BhavdipPathar it's done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi As I told you create the new thread and inside it you are updating the textview. This is the root cause of the view you are updating is not the same thread. Ideally in android Only UI thread can touch the view for update. 
Let's do blow in your code.

```
import...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView urlTextOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        new Thread() {

            final StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    String str;
                    URL url = new URL("My url");
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        text.append(str);
                    }
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored)
                {
                }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            urlTextOut.setText(text);
                        }
                    });

            }
        }.start();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me about how i can choos tag or line from my web xml